# Copying latest files (date=today) from local to HDFS with spaces in the names on daily basis

Tags: files, find, date, cp

I have daily incoming files in a local folder(/home/gas_uk). I want to put/copy the latest files from local for today to the HDFS directory (/apps/hive/warehouse/gas_uk/).
I have tried :

```
find /home/gas_uk -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr | cut -d ' ' -f5 | cut -d '/' -f7 | head
```

to find latest file but due to spaces in the name of file (eg:20191010_voice file cover.csv) I am unable to find the list.

Comment: I think the **cut -d ' ' -f5** is causing the issue here - it's cutting off anything after the first space in a filename. Need some way to trim the date fields without chopping up the filename, or a way to sort on date without adding the date info

Comment: So it worked better when I removed the -f5 section. but now I am getting 10 files when I do a head but they all do not belong to today!
Any suggestion about how we can pick latest files as per system date and not the date on files please ?

Comment: So you just want to list files for the current (todays) date? You could use the ***-mtime -1*** option for ***find***

Comment: And it worked !!

find /home/gas_uk -mtime -1 -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr | cut -d '/' -f7 | head

Thank you @Smock.

Comment: Do you have any clue on how we can send this list to hdfs ?
As files have space in names.

Comment: not so sure about that part :(

Comment: Could the files be in subdirectories of `/home/gas_uk`, or will they be directly in that directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use find's `-exec` directive to process the moves: The filenames will not be split by spaces.

```
find "$srcDir" -type f -mtime 1 -exec echo mv -t "$destDir" {} +
# ....... remove echo if it looks OK: ^^^^
```

Comment: For this kind of thing, I find that `printf '%q\n'` is a better choice than `echo`, as it helps visualise the distinct arguments.